# How to post Object data using Axios and GraphQL

Tags: graphql, axios

I am trying to post a object data with name city using mutation query and axios, but I got error Status Code: 400 Bad Request.

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/graphql/', {
  query: `
  mutation ($city:cityInput!) {
    createCity (city:$city) {
      id
      cityName
    }
  }
`,
  variables:
    '{ "city": {"cityName": "test", "cityCode": "0001", "cityEnName": "test", "cityTwName": "test", "postCode": "0001", "provinceID": 1 }}',
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Maybe because I was using object data? but I am preferred to use object data. please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code is actually working

The client:

```js
axios.post('https://o5okynl7jy.sse.codesandbox.io/', {
  query: `
  mutation ($city: CityInput!) {
    createCity (city: $city) {
      id
      cityName
    }
  }`,
  variables:
    '{ "city": {"cityName": "test", "cityCode": "0001", "cityEnName": "test", "cityTwName": "test", "postCode": "0001", "provinceID": 1 }}',
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The server:

https://codesandbox.io/s/o5okynl7jy